# Доступ сторонних скриптов (telegram) к методам vue 3

Tags: telegram-bot, vue.js, telegram, vue3

внедрил кнопку аутентификации telegram в нужно место шаблона vue 3, но не могу получить доступ к методу vue - > onTelegramAuth(user):

```
      //Загрузка кнопки Телеграма в нужное место
  const initButtonTelegram = ():void =>{
    let recaptchaScript = document.createElement('script')
    recaptchaScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?22')
    recaptchaScript.async = true
    recaptchaScript.setAttribute('data-telegram-login', '...бот...')
    recaptchaScript.setAttribute('data-size', 'small') //large
    recaptchaScript.setAttribute('data-onauth', 'onTelegramAuth(user)')
    recaptchaScript.setAttribute('data-request-access', 'write')
    target.value.appendChild(recaptchaScript)
  }
```

метод в коде vue 3

```
      function onTelegramAuth (user){
    alert('Logged in as ' + user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name + ' (' + user.id + (user.username ? ', @' + user.username : '') + ')');
  }
```

не могу разобраться как мне обратиться к методу vue (onTelegramAuth(user)), ошибка понятна, но как...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#calling-methods-in-inline-handlers

Comment: Михаил, мне кажется не совсем, то. Методом initButtonTelegram я имитирую добавление тега script в нужное мне место. Т.е. через тег script telegram добавляет кнопку. Однако  метод в script под названием onTelegramAuth (user) объявленный в коде vue не виден для кода скрипта из тега  script. Когда я помещаю функцию onTelegramAuth (user) в тег script, функция  становится видна и все гуд. А пока не получилось найти решение перейдя по ссылке. Спасибо тебе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если мне нужно вызвать метод show() из компонента vmMyObject, я делаю примерно так:

```
var appMyObject = Vue.createApp(params);
window.vmMyObject = appMyObject.mount('#place');

function myFunction (){
    window.vmMyObject.show();
}
```